# jQuery UI slider with 3 handlers: Change the color of one only handler and colorise the slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the JS code:

```
 $( "#slider-children").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 99,
        values: [10,20,25],                    
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if (!ui.handle.previousSibling) {  
                if (ui.values[0]>ui.values[1]) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }                         

            }
            else if (ui.handle.nextSibling) { 
                if (ui.values[1]<ui.values[0]) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }                               
            }                         
        }       
    });
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<span id='start-children' class="slider-tracker"></span>
<span id='end-children' class="slider-tracker"></span>
<span id='new-children' class="slider-tracker"></span>
<div id='slider-children'></div>
```

I have implemented a slider with a double functionality by adding 3 handlers. I would like to **colourise the slider among the first two handlers** and also give a **background colour to the third handler**.How may I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate the behavior of slider's default range widget.

HTML:

```
<div id='start-children' class="slider-tracker"></div>
<div id='end-children' class="slider-tracker"></div>
<div id='new-children' class="slider-tracker"></div>
<div id='slider-children'>
   <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-slider-handle:nth-child(4) {
   background: red;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  background: cyan;
}
```

And finally the JavaScript:

**EDIT**: Thanks to TigOldBitties, now updates the range after the widget is created.

```
var $range = $(".ui-slider-range");

$("#slider-children").slider({
 min: 0,
 max: 99,
 values: [10, 20, 25],
 slide: function(event, ui) {
   $range.css('left', ui.values[0] + '%');
   $range.css('width', (ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]) + '%');

   if (!ui.handle.previousSibling) {
     if (ui.values[0] > ui.values[1]) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
     }
   } else if (ui.handle.nextSibling) {
     if (ui.values[1] < ui.values[0]) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
     }
   }
 },
 create: function(event, ui) {
   var values = $(this).slider("values");
   $range.css('left', values[0] + '%');
   $range.css('width', (values[1] - values[0]) + '%');
 }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jbwbotd/2/

Comment: Great answer man, but for completeness, also handle the create method so the range is properly displayed from the start, like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0jbwbotd/2/

Comment: Kudos to you Mehmet

Comment: *Meant to say create event

Comment: yw @MehmetBaker